# SQL Query-employee ID

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table which contains values in `employee_id` that have a length of 5, 6 or 8 digits. My parent reports employee id is 8 digit.

If it's 5 digits, I want to add `100`, if it's 6 digits add `10` and if 8 digits no change.

How do I write a query in SQL to make all employee id to 8 digits ?

Here is my code :

```
case 
    when length(`Employee ID`)=6 then RIGHT(CONCAT("10" , `Employee ID`), 8) AS `Employee ID`
    when length(`Employee ID`)=5 then RIGHT(CONCAT("100" , `Employee ID`), 8) AS `Employee ID`
    else length(`Employee ID`)=8
END
```

But no luck. It failed.

Thanks.

Comment: which datatype? varchar? integer? if it's integer, why do you use length(..) instead of mathematical comparison (e.g. <1000000)?

Comment: I think the last part `else length('Employee ID')=8 END` is incorrect. Try changing to `ELSE 'Employee ID' END` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the `employee_id` is numeric, I would do:

```
SELECT employee_id, 
    CASE 
        WHEN employee_id >= 10000000
        THEN employee_id
        ELSE employee_id + 10000000
    END new_employee_id
FROM t
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kbLEgwBnQQVmtCad1BEeAf/1)**:

```
| employee_id | new_employee_id |
| ----------- | --------------- |
| 12345678    | 12345678        |
| 123456      | 10123456        |
| 12345       | 10012345        |
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, I am not looking to add the new new employee id  to the existing table. Just convert the employee ID.

Comment: @S.Y.K.J: that's what the query does: `new_employee_id` is the *converted* `employee_id`.

Comment: I never thought of doing it like that @GMB . It's much simpler.

Comment: @tcadidot0: yes... Since you are dealing with numbers, using numeric operations is much handier...

Answer (score 0):

```
case 
when length(`Employee ID`)=6 then RIGHT(CONCAT("10" , `Employee ID`), 8) AS `Employee ID`
when length(`Employee ID`)=5 then RIGHT(CONCAT("100" , `Employee ID`), 8) AS `Employee ID`
else length(`Employee ID`)=8 END
```

I have done a lot of queries like this and using `IF` as well. So, I spotted a few mistakes. From what I know, you don't need to specify `RIGHT` in a `CONCAT`. And you don't need to define each `WHEN ... THEN .. AS`, rather you define `AS` after `END`. And adding to my comment above, the last part is also incorrect. Try this query below and seeif you can get your desired result:

```
CASE
WHEN LENGTH(`Employee ID`)=6 THEN CONCAT("10" , `Employee ID`)
WHEN LENGTH(`Employee ID`)=5 THEN CONCAT("100" , `Employee ID`)
ELSE `Employee ID` END AS `Employee ID`;
```